# Getting order/invoice emails when paying with paypal

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, paypal, invoice

I am using Magento 1.9.2.4 and the payment method "Paypal Website Payments Standard (Includes Express Checkout)" with live data.

I also configured that when Emails are being sent that I get the order and invoice emails as BCC.

Unfortunately only the buyer gets an email.

Could you help me solve the issue? And maybe explain why I don't get e copy of the mail?

Answer (score 1):

Check once in admin.
`Admin-->system-->configuration-->sales-->sales emails`
[image]

Comment: These settings are in place and correct. In the database the table core_email_queue and core_email_queue_recipient new order entries are also getting filled and also always marked as processed when the cron runs. But the BCC emails never receives a copy. And sometimes the original emails don't get send.